# Why do JavaScript enumerator methods generally accept a context?

Tags: javascript

Most libraries with enumerator methods (even native JavaScript, I think) allow the passing of a `context` for the iterator.

```
function reduce(iterator, memo, context){
    this.each(function(item, idx, list){
        memo = iterator.call(context, memo, item, idx, list)
    });
    return memo;
}
```

The question is why when `bind` can easily offer the same feature?

```
stooges.reduce(function(memo, stooge){
  ...
}, context) // as argument vs...

stooges.reduce(function(memo, stooge){
  ...
}.bind(context))
```

Is this something that exists for the time being since `bind` is not readily available on all platforms?  Or is it simply because there is less overhead to `call`ing than `bind`ing?  I always read that the fewer arguments a function takes the better.  That is a function taking 0 args is better than one taking 1 is better than one taking 2, etc.

Comment: Almost certainly because `Function.bind` is not (yet) supported by all browsers, but this is kind of a subjective question. You might be better off asking some library authors.

Comment: Does that stand to reason that when it is, this context passing will change?

Comment: It'll change when the authors change it, and no sooner.

Comment: It should be preferred over `.bind()` as it's a much lighter weight solution.

Comment: @CrazyTrain "lighter weight" in what way?

Comment: @MattBall: You're not creating a new function object with the context argument.

Comment: New function syntax in ES6 with lexically defined `this` will render them both obsolete.

Comment: Calling the *this* keyword "context" doesn't seem appropriate. The term context is used in EMCA-262 to reference [execution context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10), which is a lot more than simply whatever *this* references. Given that in ES5 *this* may be undefined or null, it seems even more inappropriate there. I think *this* should simply be called *thisObj* or *thisRef*, which is the same number of characters as *context* and much more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.bind` create and return a new function. In some case, you prefer to limit the number of objects/variables created by the javascript VM so you leverage the garbage collector cleaning cycles.

Also, `bind` is known to be quite slower than "emulated" binding solutions (using `call` and `apply`): [Why is Function.prototype.bind slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656106/why-is-function-prototype-bind-slow)

Otherwise, it's often nicer and more readable to pass a context as a parameter.

ES6 arrow functions will allow to keep lexical `this`, so it'll be even easier:

```
// considering object context
var self = this;
stooges.reduce((memo, stooge) => (this === self));
```