# JavaScript: setTimeout (setInterval) not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, nested

Ok, so basically i'm creating an Interval class to handle repeating actions.
I have something like this:

```js
function Interval(fn, speed) {
 this.fn = fn;
 this.speed = speed;
 this.nt = setInterval(fn, speed);
}
```

And then i have 3 methods:

```js
 this.pause = function() {
  clearInterval(this.nt);
 }

 this.start = function() {
  this.nt = setInterval(this.fn, this.speed);
  return this.nt;
 }

 this.wait = function(time) {
  this.pause();
  setTimeout(function() {
   this.start();
  }, time);
 }
```

The problem appears in the third method. `this.pause();` and `this.start();` works as expected. But when I nest `this.start` into a `setTimeout` function it stops working. I don't understand why. Here's an example:

```js
var i = 0:
var nt = new Interval(function() {
    alert('Itineration: '+ i );
    if(i>5);
    nt.pause();
    setTimeout(nt.start, 2000);
    // nt.wait(2000);
  }, 500);
```

Neither `nt.wait(2000);` nor `nt.pause(); setTimeout(nt.start, 2000);` is working.

Comment: The answer below is correct, but in your code why do you have `if(i>5);` ?

Comment: This question has been asked about a dozen times. Search harder for an answer. Start off with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749244/javascript-setinterval-and-this-solution. Or, just debug your code. Place a breakpoint inside `this.start`, and examine the value of `this`. Voila.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside the timeout handler is not the `Interval` object, it is referring to the window object(not strict mode) so `this.start()` will not work

One solution is to pass a custom context using Function.bind()

```
this.wait = function (time) {
    this.pause();
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.start();
    }.bind(this), time);
    // setTimeout(this.start.bind(this), time) as @elclanrs suggested
}
```

Comment: Why not `setTimeout(this.start.bind(this), time)`?

Comment: Would like to give -1 for failing to point out that this is a frequent duplicate and not pointing to a more authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a context issue with your code. When the setTimeout function executes your callback the definition of "this" is no longer your Interval object. You need to modify your code so that you maintain a proper reference to the Interval object.

```
this.wait = function(time) {
    var interval = this;
    interval.pause();
    setTimeout(function() {
        interval.start();
    }, time);
}
```

**Edit**

I just saw the other answer using **.bind** which is a much cleaner solution from a readability standpoint. One important note about **.bind** is that behind the scenes it basically generates another function to call your original function using the **.call** or **.apply** methods to set the correct value of **this**

In most cases the readability gained from using **.bind** is worth it. However, if this is going to be a core component to a larger system, it is a good idea to squeeze every ounce of performance you can out of it. Which would be an argument for avoiding **.bind** in this specific situation.

Comment: What you say is "one important note about **.bind** is not a note, it's actually the fundamental thing that `bind` does for a living. Your point about performance is quite misplaced. First, you have no way to know that calling `bind` is going to be faster or slower than writing out the anonymous function inline. Second, the probability that whatever difference there is is going to affect the performance of the app is vanishingly small.

Comment: Agree on both points. As a said in my answer, bind is a much more readable and pleasant solution. Again, to my point, it is more of a black box. The performance varies by browser and if you are trying to squeeze every ounce of performance, you might opt to not use it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656106/why-is-function-prototype-bind-slow

Answer (score 0):

Working example based on the other answers.

```js
function Interval(fn, speed) {
    this.fn = fn;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.nt = setInterval(fn, speed);

    this.pause = function () {
        clearInterval(this.nt);
    }

    this.start = function () {
        this.nt = setInterval(this.fn, this.speed);
        return this.nt;
    }

    this.wait = function (time) {
        this.pause();
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.start();
        }.bind(this), time);
    }
}

var i = 0;
var nt = new Interval(function () {
    document.write('<pre>Itineration: ' + i + '</pre>');
    i++;
    nt.wait(2000);  
}, 500);
```